# Grouping records and counting within groups

Tags: python, grouping

I have API data in JSON format.

```
{
    "players": [{
        "player_full_name": "ghny",

        "url": "...",

    }]
}
```

I need to group all records by division and get the count of players.

```
    players = json_response.get("players")


    # players = players("event")



    print(division)
```

Comment: This website is not for letting other people do your coding assignments. Write code, and when you have a question about the code you have written, ask it.

Comment: You'll have to show a bit more effort... Just a hint: `players` is a list of dicts, not a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to only count players, you can simply use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections#collections.Counter) with a generator expression.

```
from collections import Counter

... # process json to get an iterable named 'players'

Counter(player.get('division') for player in players)
```

If you need to keep the results for further processing, I would suggest that either you use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools#itertools.groupby) or look at something like the [`toolz`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library, which provides a friendlier api for groupby.

If you plan on sticking with `itertools.groupby`, you will need to do something like:

```
player_division = lambda player: player.get('division') 
g = groupby(sorted(players, key=player_division), player_division)
players_by_division = {division: list(players) for division, players in g}
```

**Note**: the input to `itertools.groupby` has to be sorted in order to work properly

Comment: @kprcse you would still need to import it from itertools (`from itertools import groupby`)

Comment: Either you would use the first method I mentioned using `Counter` with the initial list, or you would do an expression like `{division: len(players) for division, players in players_by_division.items()}`. Or, if you only care about one division, you would do `len(players_by_division[division_name])`, where `division_name` is the string for the division you want

Comment: Are you calling `Counter` on a single division?

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work and is not what I originally said to do. `counts = Counter(player.get('division') for player in players)` will get how many players are associated with each division. What you're doing is counting how often letters occur in each player's division's name